# boost::asio::steady_timer get stuck at WaitForSingleObject when built as a DLL

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-asio, asio

I've just encountered a weird and devastating problem that I couldn't find any information about it anywhere.

> asio::steady_timer timer(m_context);

This `asio::steady_timer` works perfectly fine if I'm building it as an EXE, but if it's built as a DLL it will be stuck waiting for `WaitForSingleObject` (in `win_thread.ipp` file, line 106) whenever initialize a `asio::steady_timer`, please take a look at the picture below.

[image: asio::steady_timer stuck]

This DLL is just an empty project, it only includes the `asio.hpp` file. I've found [this_article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808945/waitforsingleobject-with-thread-handle-get-stuck-while-running-regsvr32-exe) about a problem that might be relevant, but still found no way to debug or fix this.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this the library's bug?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I post the screenshot for the stack traces, the code is really just that 1 line

Comment: @thedemons The code is **crucially** inside DllMain, it is *not* the single line.

Comment: You need to redesign your code to make required initialization by caller request. `DllMain` is not a place for non-trivial tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by making these two class members or global variables and not initializing them in the entry point of the DLL.

```cpp
asio::io_context context;
asio::steady_timer timer(context);
```